# Deserializar Array JSON obtenida a través de método post en c#

Tags: c#, json, rest, post, restsharp

espero tengan un buen lunes. Mi pregunta es cómo puedo deserializar un JSON que contiene una array para poder mostrar un dato dentro de ella.
Tengo este JSON obtenido a través de método POST:

```js
{
  "compromiso": {
    "id": null,
    "titulo": "example 1",
     "descripcion": "Descrpción 1",
    "documentos": {
      "documento": [{
        "numero": "128",
        "monto": 100,
        "tipo": "17",
        "fecha": "2019-01-09-03:00",
        "descripcion": "example 1 metodo post",
        "idDocumentoAjustado": 14,
        "tipoDeCambio": {
          "fecha": null,
          "moneda": "CLP"
        },
        "principales": {
          "principal": [{
            "id": "123",
            "transaccionesPrevias": {
              "transaccion": [{
                "folio": 2,
                "tipo": "01",
                "idCombinacion": "123",
                "agrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos": {
                  "agrupacion": [{
                    "imputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion": {
                      "catalogo": [{
                          "catalogo": "programaPresupuestario",
                          "elemento": "01"
                        },
                        {
                          "catalogo": "ProductosEstrategicos",
                          "elemento": "00"
                        },
                        {
                          "catalogo": "UnidadesDemandantes",
                          "elemento": "00"
                        },
                        {
                          "catalogo": "iniciativaInversion",
                          "elemento": "00"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "imputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios": {
                      "imputacion": [{
                        "idConcepto": "021",
                        "nombreConcepto": "apoyo restapi",
                        "monto": 100,
                        "montoFuturo": null,
                        "saldo": 100
                      }]
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }]
            },
            "cumplimientos": {
              "cumplimiento": [{
                "fecha": "2019-12-31-03:00",
                "monto": 100
              }]
            }
          }]
        },
        "imputacionesAGlosas": null,
        "camposVariables": null
      }]
    },
    "etapa": "Compromiso Cierto",
    "informacionDeAjuste": null
  },
  "status": "OK",
  "descripcion": "",
  "errors": []
}
```

Como pueden ver documento es un Array, ya que este json obtenido puede tener varios documentos dentro.
Usando Json2Sharp obtuve las clases del Json para poder deserializarlo, donde obtuve las siguientes.

```
 public class TipoDeCambio
{
    public object fecha { get; set; }
    public string moneda { get; set; }
}

public class Catalogo
{
    public string catalogo { get; set; }
    public string elemento { get; set; }
}

public class ImputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion
{
    public List<Catalogo> catalogo { get; set; }
}

public class Imputacion
{
    public string idConcepto { get; set; }
    public string nombreConcepto { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
    public object montoFuturo { get; set; }
    public int saldo { get; set; }
}

public class ImputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios
{
    public List<Imputacion> imputacion { get; set; }
}

public class Agrupacion
{
    public ImputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion imputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion { get; set; }
    public ImputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios imputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios { get; set; }
}

public class AgrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos
{
    public List<Agrupacion> agrupacion { get; set; }
}

public class Transaccion
{
    public int folio { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string idCombinacion { get; set; }
    public AgrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos agrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos { get; set; }
}

public class TransaccionesPrevias
{
    public List<Transaccion> transaccion { get; set; }
}

public class Cumplimiento
{
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
}

public class Cumplimientos
{
    public List<Cumplimiento> cumplimiento { get; set; }
}

public class Principal
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public TransaccionesPrevias transaccionesPrevias { get; set; }
    public Cumplimientos cumplimientos { get; set; }
}

public class Principales
{
    public List<Principal> principal { get; set; }
}

public class Documento
{
    public string numero { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int idDocumentoAjustado { get; set; }
    public TipoDeCambio tipoDeCambio { get; set; }
    public Principales principales { get; set; }
    public object imputacionesAGlosas { get; set; }
    public object camposVariables { get; set; }
}

public class Documentos
{
    public List<Documento> documento { get; set; }
}

public class Compromiso
{
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public Documentos documentos { get; set; }
    public string etapa { get; set; }
    public object informacionDeAjuste { get; set; }
}

public class obtenerCompromiso1
{
    public Compromiso compromiso { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
}
```

Logre deserializar compromiso con la librería RESTSHARP para obtener la descrpción con el siguiente código:

```
    obtenerCompromiso1 compromiso = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<obtenerCompromiso1>(response);
    Console.WriteLine(compromiso.compromiso.descripcion);
```

Pero no he podido entrar a documentos, lo intente con el siguiente código:

```
Documento doc = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Documento>(response);
```

y puedo entrar a:

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.numero);
```

Pero no me muestra nada, espero puedan ayudarme. Desde ya muchas gracias.
Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado.
hay que agregar el número del array al que quieres entrar:

```
Console.WriteLine(compromiso.compromiso.documentos.documento[0].numero);
```

Si no le agregas [0] no te muestra el número. Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien más le sirve